# Can I bury RG6 in the same conduit as electric?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, coaxial-cable

I am burying electric wire in a PVC conduit from my house to my shed, I want to run RG6 cable for cable TV also, can I run the RG6 in the same conduit as the electric wire? without any trouble or interference?

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot. Unless you're not covered by National Electrical Code (or similar), you don't care about following codes, or you're also installing a permanent barrier or listed divider.

> ## National Electrical Code
>
> ### Chapter 8 Communications Systems.
>
> #### Article 820 Community Antenna Television and Radio Distribution Systems.
>
> **820.133 Installation of Coaxial Cables and Equipment.**
>   Beyond the point of grounding, as defined in 820.93, the
>   coaxial cable installation shall comply with 820.133(A)
>   and (B).
>
> **(A) Separation from Other Conductors.**
>
> **(1) In Raceways, Cable Trays, and Boxes.**
>
> *(b) Electric Light, Power, Class 1, Non–Power-Limited
>   Fire Alarm, and Medium-Power Network-Powered Broadband
>   Communications Circuits.* Coaxial cable shall not be
>   placed in any raceway, compartment, outlet box, junction
>   box, or other enclosures with conductors of electric light,
>   power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm, or medium-power
>   network-powered broadband communications
>   circuits.
>
> *Exception No. 1: Where all of the conductors of electric
>   light, power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm, and
>   medium-power network-powered broadband communications
>   circuits are separated from all of the coaxial cables by
>   a permanent barrier or listed divider.*

You can Either put a second conduit in the trench for communications circuits, or put direct-burial coaxial cable in the trench.

Comment: Conduit, conduit, conduit. Direct burial is a dirty word when you have the expensive part (trench) done. Conduit means never having to dig that trench again - direct burial just about guarantees that you will have to dig it over.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I agree that conduit is useful if you ever have to run cable again, but direct burial cable is easier and cheaper to install and should last quite a long time.